# Gaining points for posting

Tags: discussion, support, comments, reputation, privileges

How do I earn 50 points to comment if I am not allowed to comment or post? So my problem is as described as far you can see.

Comment: By asking well received questions or answering other users' questions

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not allowed to comment or post"? -- As far as I can see, you are neither blocked from asking nor blocked from answering. You can add comments to other peoples' posts once you gained 50 points for your questions or answers (50 points correspond to a total of 5 upvotes).

Comment: Also, commenting does not earn you points.